# Access2019のACE.OLEDBがWindows10にインストールできない。

Tags: c#, ms-access

お世話になります。

VisualStudio2019CommunityのC#で、AccessのDBを操作するプログラムを組もうとしたのですが、
ACE.OLEDBが入っていないということで、公式から『accessdatabaseengine.exe』(2016版、番号は16.0の方)をダウンロードしてきたのですが、
なぜかエラーでインストールできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

使用しているPCはもちろんWindows10Proの64bitですが、AccessやExcelなどのOfficeはすべて32bitです。
それに合わせてインストーラーも32bitにしたつもりなのですが、エラー内容を漠然と見てみると
64bitだからダメとかどうとか言われるのですが、それが何故だか解りません。

今使用しているAccessは2019のダウンロード版ですが、そこに何かのバージョンの違いのようなものが
あるからなのでしょうか。

ご助力をお願いいたします。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[Microsoft Acces Database Engine 2016 の32bit/64bit版の共存方法](https://qiita.com/Y_MAGARI000/items/5f6735c5c870069b08b7), [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDBについてまとめてみた](https://qiita.com/yaju/items/7b0aa9e9f30005f60388) あと(画面ではEnglishとあるので日本語と)違いがあるのか不明ですが。[Microsoft Access データベース エンジン 2016 再頒布可能コンポーネント](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=54920) あるいは古い記事(状況が変わってるかも)でこんなのも。[【なんとか解決】Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 プロバイダーはローカルのコンピューターに登録されていません。](https://you-1.tokyo/microsoft-ace-oledb-16-0/)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。助かります。いろいろと試してみたのですが、どれも的を得ていませんでした。そんな中、偶然解決の記事がありましたので、そちらを参考にやってみました。自己レスにはなりますが、ご確認くだされば幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

自己レスですが、解決となる記事を見つけましたので、リンクを記述します。

http://www.i-d-a.jp/blog161206235458.html

どうやら、レジストリに何かしらの残骸が残っていて、それがあるためにできないようでした。
その記事をもとに試したところ、インストール『は』何とか成功しました。